# Read Tab Delineated Produces Data With /t s

Tags: r, file, etl

I'm trying to open a tab delineated file using the following code:

```
x <- read.table("C:/FilePath.txt", sep = '\t')

head(x)
```

This returns:

```
                                    CatalogId.Code.Name
1     386\t239\tPRODUCT1 1.75oz Each\t\t\t\t\t
2       386\t243\tPRODUCT2 1.75oz Each\t\t\t\t\t
3         386\t843\tPRODUCT3 2oz Each\t\t\t\t\t
4 386\t817\tPRODUCT4 1.5oz Eac\t\t\t\t\t
5                      386\t238\tPRODUCT5 2oz Each\t\t\t\t\t
6             386\t237\tPRODUCT6 2oz Each\t\t\t\t\t
```

The file is tab delineated (checked manually).  How do I make the \t s delineate columns for a dataframe?

Comment: Can you try with `data.table::fread("C:/Filepath.txt")`

Comment: @akrun Same result now with: Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting ""C:\U"

Comment: It may be that your header is a single column.  Can you use `skip = 1, header = FALSE`

Comment: Same result. No delineation by tab character.

Comment: Can you upload a part of the file in github for testing purpose

Comment: I resolved the issue by washing the data file through Notepad and Excel, deleting the header and other underhanded methods.

Comment: Great to know that it worked for you.  It may also be due to some Encoding which gets corrected after you opened and saved from Notepad